# How to use Postgresql enum type via Kotlin Exposed ORM?

Tags: postgresql, enums, orm, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I have added some Postgresql types to Exposed as extensions. It has two ready types named `enumeration` and `enumerationByName`. I tested both of them with no success for mapping a postgre enum type to Kotlin enum class. In both reading and writing it raises error

```
enum class TicketStatus(val status: String) {
    Open("open"),
    Close("close"),
    InProgress("in_progress")
}

class Ticket(id: EntityID<UUID>) : Entity<UUID>(id) {
    companion object : EntityClass<UUID, Ticket>(Tickets)

    var geom by Tickets.geom
    var description by Tickets.description
    var status by Tickets.status
    var createdAt by Tickets.createdAt
    var updatedAt by Tickets.updatedAt
    var owner by Tickets.owner
}
```

When reading:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: open is not valid for enum TicketStatus
```

Comment: Maybe it's *case sensitive*? Try to either rename the elements to `open`, `close` etc. or read some upper-cased names from the DB.

Comment: @hotkey Before the question it was so! Does not work!

Comment: Where is your "Tickets" object? How do you declare status?

Answer (score 15):

You should declare status column as follow:

```kotlin
object Tickets: Table() {
   val status = enumeration("status", TicketStatus::class.java) // will create integer column
   val status = enumerationByName("status", TicketStatus::class.java) // will create varchar with TicketStatus names
}
```

In the new version:

```kotlin
object Tickets: Table() {
   val status = enumeration("status", TicketStatus::class) // will create integer column
   val status = enumerationByName("status", 10, TicketStatus::class) // will create varchar with TicketStatus names
}
```

Comment: fails with "... of org.postgresql.util.PGobject is not valid for enum ..." for me

Comment: @Tapac it seems with newer version of Expose, you should use just `TicketStatus::class` , at least for me adding `.java` did not work.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is an old question, but if anyone is still looking for an answer here you go:

Exposed has a `customEnumeration` that can be used to deal with Enums, and is particularly useful if you are using Strings, or another non-default enumerator to back your enum.

For postgres, you'll first need to define a class like so:

```
class PGEnum<T:Enum<T>>(enumTypeName: String, enumValue: T?) : PGobject() {
    init {
        value = enumValue?.name
        type = enumTypeName
    }
}
```

Then in your table definition, use the following to define your column, replacing the placeholders as necessary:

```
val enumColumn = customEnumeration(
            "ENUM_COLUMN",
            "ENUM_SCHEMA.ENUM_TYPE",
            { value ->
                when (value) {
                    is PGobject -> LocalEnumClass.valueOf(value.value)
                    is String -> LocalEnumClass.valueOf(value)
                    else -> error("Can't convert ENUM_COLUMN")
                }
            },
            { PGEnum("ENUM_SCHEMA.ENUM_TYPE", it) }
)
```

I was running into the same `org.postgresql.util.PGobject is not valid for enum` before I did this.

[See here for more information, and for non-Postgres databases](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DataTypes#how-to-use-database-enum-types)

Answer (score 1):

While other answers are useful, no one shown a way to automatically create and update enums based on a Kotlin enum. The enum will be stored in PostgreSQL as the name of the class, but in lowercase. Values will have the same name as their Java/Kotlin counterparts.

```kotlin
/**
 * Creates and updates a PostgreSQL enum based on a Kotlin enum
 *
 * **This does not remove values from the PostgreSQL enum, and it does not insert new enums based on order!**
 *
 * @param enumValues a callback that provides a list of the valid enum values
 */
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> Transaction.createOrUpdatePostgreSQLEnum(enumValues: Array<T>) {
    val valueNames = enumValues.map { it.name }
    val clazzName = T::class.simpleName!!
    val psqlType = clazzName.lowercase()
    val joined = valueNames.joinToString { "'$it'" }

    val alreadyInsertedEnumValues = mutableSetOf<String>()

    exec("SELECT  n.nspname AS enum_schema,  \n" +
            "        t.typname AS enum_name,  \n" +
            "        e.enumlabel AS enum_value\n" +
            "FROM    pg_type t JOIN \n" +
            "        pg_enum e ON t.oid = e.enumtypid JOIN \n" +
            "        pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace\n" +
            "WHERE   t.typname = '$psqlType'") {
        while (it.next())
            alreadyInsertedEnumValues.add(it.getString("enum_value"))
    }

    val missingEnums = valueNames.filter { it !in alreadyInsertedEnumValues }

    if (alreadyInsertedEnumValues.isEmpty()) {
        exec("CREATE TYPE ${clazzName.lowercase()} AS ENUM ($joined);")
    } else if (missingEnums.isNotEmpty()) {
        for (missingEnum in missingEnums) {
            exec("ALTER TYPE ${clazzName.lowercase()} ADD VALUE '$missingEnum';")
        }
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> Table.postgresEnumeration(
    columnName: String
) = customEnumeration(columnName, T::class.simpleName!!.lowercase(),
    { value -> enumValueOf<T>(value as String) }, { PGEnum(T::class.simpleName!!.lowercase(), it) })

// From https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DataTypes
class PGEnum<T : Enum<T>>(enumTypeName: String, enumValue: T?) : PGobject() {
    init {
        value = enumValue?.name
        type = enumTypeName
    }
}
```

You can use it in your table like this:

```kotlin
object EnumExample : LongIdTable() {
    val type = postgresEnumeration<AchievementType>("type")
}
```

Keep in mind that you need to create the enum BEFORE creating the table that uses the enum!

```kotlin
transaction {
    createOrUpdatePostgreSQLEnum(AchievementType.values())

    SchemaUtils.createMissingTablesAndColumns(
        EnumTable
    )
}
```

I've also published a library with this code: https://github.com/PerfectDreams/ExposedPowerUtils

Answer (score 0):

I created this extension function to work with postgres enums:

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> Table.postgresEnumeration(
   columnName: String,
   postgresEnumName: String
) = customEnumeration(columnName, postgresEnumName,
    { value -> enumValueOf<T>(value as String) }, { PGEnum(postgresEnumName, it) })
```

Then you can use like this:

```
 val theEnumColum = postgresEnumeration<YourEnumClass>("your_cloumn_name",
 "your_postgres_enum_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use without parameters, postgres and H2 database

```
val db = Database.connect(.....)

val isPg get() = db.dialect.name == "postgresql"
val isH2 get() = db.dialect.name == "h2"

inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> Table.customEnum(): Column<T> {
    val columnName = T::class.simpleName?.lowercase()!!
    val sqlPg = "${T::class.simpleName?.lowercase()}_type"
    val sqlH2 = "ENUM(${enumValues<T>().joinToString { "'${it.name}'" }})"
    val fromDb: (Any) -> T = { enumValueOf(it as String) }
    return when {
        isPg -> customEnumeration(columnName, sqlPg, fromDb) { PGEnum(sqlPg, it) }
        isH2 -> customEnumeration(columnName, sqlH2, fromDb) { it.name }
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown db")
    }
}
```

Use

```
val status = customEnum<Status>()
```

or

```
val status:Column<Status> = customEnum()
```

Add enum type in postgres

```
class BuilderEnum {
    private val list = mutableListOf<String>()
    inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> addEnumType() = addEnumType(T::class)
    fun <T : Enum<T>> addEnumType(c: KClass<T>) = apply {list.add(addEnumTypeExecSql(c)) }
    fun build() = transaction { list.forEach { exec(it) } }
}

fun <T : Enum<T>> addEnumTypeExecSql(enum: KClass<T>): String {
    val enumTypeName = "${enum.simpleName?.lowercase()}_enum_type"
    return """
        DO $$
        BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pg_type WHERE typname = '$enumTypeName') THEN
          CREATE TYPE $enumTypeName AS ENUM (${enum.java.enumConstants.joinToString { "'${it}'" }});
        END IF;
        END $$;
    """.trimIndent()
}
```

use

```
BuilderEnum()
    .addEnumType<Role>()
    .addEnumType<Status>()
    .build()
```